# Relate rows based on one or two fields

Tags: python, excel, powerbi, relationship

I am open to solutions using Python, PowerBI, and/or Excel/VBA for this.

I have a dataset full of addresses and names. A name can be related to many addresses and there can be many names related to an address.

Example dataset:

| Address | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 XYZ | John Smith |
| 123 XYZ | Greg Jones |
| 456 ABC | Greg Jones |
| 456 ABC | Bob Jackson |
| 789 DEF | Karen Johnson |

Required Solution:

I am looking to find a way to relate rows that share an address or a name at some level. For example, John Smith is clearly associated with Greg Jones as they both share an address at 123 XYZ, but at the secondary level, John Smith is related to Bob Jackson through Greg Jones, as Bob and Greg share an address at 456 ABC. I'd like to assign a unique ID to each set of relationships - so John, Greg, and Bob would all be related using the field, while Karen would not.

Example Output:

| Address | Name | Relationship ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 XYZ | John Smith | 1 |
| 123 XYZ | Greg Jones | 1 |
| 456 ABC | Greg Jones | 1 |
| 456 ABC | Bob Jackson | 1 |
| 789 DEF | Karen Johnson | 2 |

Appreciate any help here!

Comment: nice one - will come back to this when I hav time bro

Comment: Would appreciate it, thanks dude!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick solution using Python:

After opening your dataset (as a CSV file) and converting it to a list of dictionaries, I used sets and conditions to account for the first and second-level relationships, and gave each row a new attribute - "relationship_id".

```
import csv

with open("data_in.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    dataset = list(csv.DictReader(file))

    addresses = set()
    names = set()

    relationship_id = 0
    for row in dataset:
        address = row["address"]
        name = row["name"]
    
        if name not in names and address not in addresses:
            relationship_id += 1
    
        if address not in addresses:
            addresses.add(address)
        
        if address not in names:
            names.add(name)
    
        row["relationship_id"] = relationship_id
```

You can then use this list however you like. If you want to convert the updated rows into a CSV file again, you can do the following:

```
with open("data_out.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8", newline="") as file:
    fieldnames = ["address", "name", "relationship_id"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
    for row in dataset:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help on this! I am not sure if this is a me issue or not, but I am getting keyerror for the first column (in this case the address column). I've verified I am typing everything correct but cannot get past the error. Still get the error when I apply your solution using Pandas as well. Any ideas? Sorry if that is a very basic level question but it's driving me insane!